# Debian OpenVPN server with multiple users

Tags: debian, openvpn, vpn

it is possible to setup a OpenVPN server with multiple clients, which are using username and password for the authentication instead of files?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: @jordanm, I just need to have multiple username on my Debian? Or It is possible to have the same username with multiple clients?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an in-depth tutorial [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-openvpn-server-on-debian-8). There is also a similar question with an answer on AskUbuntu [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/193611/203540).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.
Simply add the following line to your server config file (usually at /etc/openvpn/server.conf) -
`duplicate-cn`
Don't forget to restart the openvpn service after changing that file.